# Is it possible to see system's user desktop? How to desktop of your user from another session?

Tags: session, windows-7, windows-services, desktop

I run Windows 7.
I run windows service that runs a program with GUI.
I cannot see the GUI of my program because it was started from another session by system or even my user.

Is there a way for me to see my program?
Switch desktop to system user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SetThreadDesktop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686250%28VS.85%29.aspx) to change the thread's context in your service to the user's desktop.

- `SetThreadDesktop()` takes a handle to the desktop as it's first parameter;  to get that handle, use [`EnumDesktops()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682614%28VS.85%29.aspx).
- `EnumDesktops()` takes a handle to the window station as it's first parameter; to get that handle, use [`EnumWindowStations()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682644%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

To understand what's going on with Window Stations and Desktops, try reading [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681928%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from from MSDN.

Be cautious with this technique.  Higher-privileged processes (i.e., services) interacting with the user's desktop are the basis for [shatter attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack).  You need to write a separate application that runs in the user's context and communicates with your service via pipes or similar.

Comment: that should solve my problem, **BUT** I would also like to know if there is a way to login/switch user to system user/local service user/network service user/**same user that i am logged in**. I see in taskmanager that there is an instance of a program that is run by my user but i cant see it. Is there a way to see if **after** windows service has invoked it?

Comment: That's usually done with ImpersonateLoggedOnUser() or one of it's cousins in the API:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx